# how to set autoconfig.url python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, webproxy

In Java i am able to set AutoConfigUrl like mentioned below,

how to do the same in python ?

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
              
proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl("http://wpad/wpad.dat");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *Python* and [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to set the [proxyAutoconfigUrl](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.proxy.html#selenium.webdriver.common.proxy.Proxy.proxyAutoconfigUrl) you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy


prox = Proxy()
prox.proxyAutoconfigUrl = "http://wpad/wpad.dat"
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
```